# If statement bodycnot being executed in C

Tags: c, debugging

Why is does the `tolower(*(text+i));` in my if statement not get executed when I run the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void vowel_caser(char text[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(*(text+i) != '\0')
    {
        if (*(text+i) == 'A' || *(text+i) == 'E' || *(text+i) == 'I' || *(text+i) == 'O' || *(text+i) == 'U')
        {
            tolower(*(text+i));
        }
        i++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char test[] = "This is An example";
    vowel_caser(test);
    puts(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and step through the code to find out for yourself. But my guess is you are reaching the wrong conclusion. It does execute. Also, read the `tolower` man page.

Comment: Stop using `*(text+i)` and write `text[i]` like a normal programmer.

Answer (score 4):

`tolower` ***returns*** the new value.
It does not modify the value in-place.

If you wish to modify the character, you need:

```
 text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
```

Comment: More generally, function parameters are passed by value, so functions *can't* modify them in place. The exception is arrays, which are converted to pointers.